# Creating a loading circle/wheel (similar to the one in ProgressDialog, but without the dialog)

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

As you know, when using a ProgressDialog a "popup"/dialog appears in which a circle/wheel shows the progress.

I am interested in drawing this wheel **out** from the dialog box, and only displaying this wheel, still indicating progress.

Main reason to want this, is the fact that I have some sort of "intro screen" which will show a logo and this progress wheel just below, which indicates that the application is loading various content.

This is (or could be) the wheel in question:

[image: wheel]

It wouldn't hurt if the wheel could be smaller than it appears in a regular ProgressDialog.

(I'm using AsyncTask to load the content while this wheel is displayed.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pre-defined style Android provides for an indeterminate `ProgressBar`, like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

If you want it to be smaller, use the `progressBarStyleSmall` style instead.

From here you can set the visibility of the `ProgressBar` to make it appear/disappear whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and setting [setIndeterminate(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29);